# SectionHeader Open/Close Animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I have implemented a tableView with section headers that unfold cells when tapped. It si pretty much just a big button on the section header and when it is pressed I calculate which cells need to be deleted and then call:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
//delete necessary cells 
[tableView endUpdates];
```

My problem lies in the animation of this. It works fine when You open one section and then either open another or close that same one without having to scroll the tableView. But if you do end up scrolling the table view and then you open another one, A very strange thing happens. One of the section headers slides to the bottom of the screen and then back into its place. For the animation I just call `deleteRowsAtIndexPathsWithAnimation` and the opposite insert method with the automatic tableView animation type. Does anybody know why this happens?

There is an apple sample code called TVAnimationsGestures (it comes up if you just search for tableview) that does the same thing that my program does. If you want to see more in depth the code and the problem, you should check that out.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't know why it happens, but I would guess it has something to do with the behavior of section titles. Notice when you scroll, section titles tend to "collect" at the top or bottom of the screen, to be replaced by the next section title? This might be causing your table view to distort.

Comment: Thanks gurooj, I think you may be on to something. Although I find it strange that it only happens when the tableview has been moved from its original place.

Comment: That must be when the special animations for section titles are invoked.

Comment: This was another question asked tonight that might be relevant to what you are working on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485536/uilabel-in-header-of-uitableview-in-objective-c

Comment: Have you tried scrolling the tableview row to the top of the view using something like (sorry about formatting):

    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:senderIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check is the the values your returning in numberOfSectionInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection.

I think when the tableview has to scroll it calls those methods, so if you have a mismatch in what they are returning to the number of rows in your tableView strange things can happen.

So just make sure when you remove a row that you also update the number of rows in section which are returned.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but this is not the problem as I believe I already handle this correctly.