# UILabel in header of UITableView in objective c

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, header, uilabel

I am making an iPad app where in I have a grouped TableView with headers for the sections.

i want to add four label in header of tableview

text of four label's are "company",     "current",   "prev close" ,"change"

or

instead of adding four labels in header, i want to add four text  "company",     "current",   "prev close" ,"change"

What should I do?

Please Help and Suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

There is a delegate method of UITableView for custom view of Header

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
     UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,40)];

     UILabel *objLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWiThFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,40)];
     objLabel.text = @"Post";
     [headerView addSubview:objLabel];   //Similarly You can Add any UI Component on header
     [objLabel release];

     return [headerView autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show the *Company*, *Current*, *prev next* as text in section title, then 
just append the text in a single string and return this value in the following delegate method.

```
(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can implement `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` and you can return what ever view you wanted for each header